# F-norm relation to singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

$\|A\|_F = \sqrt{tr(A^*A)} = \sqrt{tr(AA*)} = \sum_k \sigma_k$

Is the last equality true in general?

Comment: The two expressions in the middle are matrices, not numbers, and the RHS is the Ky Fan norm, which is not the Frobenius norm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm for some correct identities.

Comment: Now the middle is fine but the last equality is not true in general. As Wikipedia says the correct identity is $\| A \|_F = \sqrt{\sum \sigma_k^2}$.

Comment: Let $A = 2I$ to see that this is false.